# Passing arguments in {% url %} in Django

Tags: python, regex, django, django-templates

I've this template:

```
<ul>
    {% for url1 in urls %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'disp' url1.url_name %}">{{ url1.url_title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I'm trying to pass a Url (i.e. url1.url_name) to the view ('disp') but it's not taking it.

It's giving the following error:

```
Reverse for 'disp' with arguments '(u'file:///E:/BEPROJECT/websites_collection/katewinslet.html',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['display/(?P<webpage>[^/]+)/$']
```

Where 'file:///E:/BEPROJECT/websites_collection/katewinslet.html' is an instance of url1.

I've no idea what am I doing wrong. The problem seems to be present in the regex part of the code (I think) but I don't know how to solve it. Please help.

Comment: that is perfectly valid syntax, your regex is most likely not matching the value of url1.url_name

Comment: You shouldn't match a url on a full file path. Instead, pass the url-encoded file path as a query parameter

Answer (score 0):

As your error says, 'url1.url_name' contains nothing (i.e. keyword arguments '{}'). Check that and see why it's empty.